# aspx.vb page does not work when selecting a dropdownlist error 500

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

for days I have been trying to fix an error that appeared on a page that I am repairing.

**aspx.vb code**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb"  AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ModificaLibro.aspx.vb" Inherits="AdministracionLibros.ModificaLib"%>

<%@ Register Assembly="RJS.Web.WebControl.PopCalendar.Net.2008" Namespace="RJS.Web.WebControl"
    TagPrefix="rjs" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#f1f2d0">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div >
         <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    
             
 </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>    
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>                
        <div align="center" >
            <span class="Estilo48">
        <div align="center" >
                        Modificar libro<br />
        
        
        <span class="Estilo48">
                        <br />                        
                        <table align ="center" style="width: 304px; height: 54px;" ><tr>
                                <td align ="right" ><asp:Label runat="server" Text="Editorial:" ID="Label1" 
                                        Font-Names="MS Reference Sans Serif" Font-Size="10pt"></asp:Label>
</td><td align ="left" ><asp:DropDownList runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Font-Names="MS Reference Sans Serif" Font-Size="9pt" Width="183px" ID="Existe2">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" BackColor="#F1F2D0" BorderColor="#FFFFCC" BorderStyle="Groove" ForeColor="#F1F2D0" Height="16px" Width="16px" ID="IdC" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>


</td></tr><tr><td align ="right" ><asp:Label runat="server" Text="Genero:" ID="Label19" 
                                    Font-Names="MS Reference Sans Serif" Font-Size="10pt"></asp:Label>


/td><td align ="left" ><asp:DropDownList runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Font-Names="MS Reference Sans Serif" Font-Size="9pt" Width="183px" ID="EstacionList"></asp:DropDownList>


<asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="25px" ID="IdE" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>


</td></tr></table></span>
                        <table align ="center" style="width: 309px; height: 33px;" ><tr><td align ="right" >
        <span class="Estilo48">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Encargado:" Font-Names="MS Reference Sans Serif" Font-Size="9pt" ID="Label20"></asp:Label>
                            </span></td><td align ="left" ><span class="Estilo48">
                                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="23px" Width="230px" 
                                    ID="empleados">
                            </asp:DropDownList></span></td></tr></table></div></span></div>
                       </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>  
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server"><ContentTemplate><!--code--></ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server"><ContentTemplate><!--code--></ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server"><ContentTemplate><!--code--></ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form></body></html>
```

the error happens when I change an element in the dropdownlist "Existe2", I have been reading on several pages and this can happen when there may be a security problem.

**Error**

```
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error ocurred while processing the  request on the server. the status code returned from the server was:500
    at Function.Error$create [as create] (http://localhost:58997/ScriptResource.axd?d=_o51RmoaFE_rcurlUuuJR7kIk5N35NyYgYliYkiDuuT0q5IhjRIQS6XEEpRgVvtq4rJe1Z1Yh1trL8HXNmAbdW4deIjtWUiHhxs2WMwxMCl4u8-3-8D-pXTLHycJezeUzbjyKQ2&t=ffffffffec54f2es.js:846:15)
    at PageRequestManager$_createPageRequestManagerServerError [as _createPageRequestManagerServerError] (http://localhost:58997/ScriptResource.axd?d=fTrzH_CvX-xCkSycfocz9F4XR69OwmfI_1utNDeAQS1ZuuPHgDpL28cPN2l15Lu3zd2hP_l_opAVxvNuQywowuy0QXQvWYd_gqn-DWUj9PKtl9BVrve-vXVLXfD048NYtAACug2&t=ffffffffec54f2es.js:764:23)
    at PageRequestManager$_parseDelta [as _parseDelta] (http://localhost:58997/ScriptResource.axd?d=fTrzH_CvX-xCkSycfocz9F4XR69OwmfI_1utNDeAQS1ZuuPHgDpL28cPN2l15Lu3zd2hP_l_opAVxvNuQywowuy0QXQvWYd_gqn-DWUj9PKtl9BVrve-vXVLXfD048NYtAACug2&t=ffffffffec54f2es.js:1653:44)
    at PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmitCompleted [as _onFormSubmitCompleted] (http://localhost:58997/ScriptResource.axd?d=fTrzH_CvX-xCkSycfocz9F4XR69OwmfI_1utNDeAQS1ZuuPHgDpL28cPN2l15Lu3zd2hP_l_opAVxvNuQywowuy0QXQvWYd_gqn-DWUj9PKtl9BVrve-vXVLXfD048NYtAACug2&t=ffffffffec54f2es.js:1414:25)
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://localhost:58997/ScriptResource.axd?d=_o51RmoaFE_rcurlUuuJR7kIk5N35NyYgYliYkiDuuT0q5IhjRIQS6XEEpRgVvtq4rJe1Z1Yh1trL8HXNmAbdW4deIjtWUiHhxs2WMwxMCl4u8-3-8D-pXTLHycJezeUzbjyKQ2&t=ffffffffec54f2es.js:627:23)
    at http://localhost:58997/ScriptResource.axd?d=_o51RmoaFE_rcurlUuuJR7kIk5N35NyYgYliYkiDuuT0q5IhjRIQS6XEEpRgVvtq4rJe1Z1Yh1trL8HXNmAbdW4deIjtWUiHhxs2WMwxMCl4u8-3-8D-pXTLHycJezeUzbjyKQ2&t=ffffffffec54f2es.js:4337:23
    at raise (http://localhost:58997/ScriptResource.axd?d=_o51RmoaFE_rcurlUuuJR7kIk5N35NyYgYliYkiDuuT0q5IhjRIQS6XEEpRgVvtq4rJe1Z1Yh1trL8HXNmAbdW4deIjtWUiHhxs2WMwxMCl4u8-3-8D-pXTLHycJezeUzbjyKQ2&t=ffffffffec54f2es.js:7247:17)
    at WebRequest$completed [as completed] (http://localhost:58997/ScriptResource.axd?d=_o51RmoaFE_rcurlUuuJR7kIk5N35NyYgYliYkiDuuT0q5IhjRIQS6XEEpRgVvtq4rJe1Z1Yh1trL8HXNmAbdW4deIjtWUiHhxs2WMwxMCl4u8-3-8D-pXTLHycJezeUzbjyKQ2&t=ffffffffec54f2es.js:7251:9)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost:58997/ScriptResource.axd?d=_o51RmoaFE_rcurlUuuJR7kIk5N35NyYgYliYkiDuuT0q5IhjRIQS6XEEpRgVvtq4rJe1Z1Yh1trL8HXNmAbdW4deIjtWUiHhxs2WMwxMCl4u8-3-8D-pXTLHycJezeUzbjyKQ2&t=ffffffffec54f2es.js:6856:35)
```

I have been looking for the error in several pages, but there is not much information about it. I already did everything I have found but nothing works.

Comment: Please don't spam unrelated tags if you are specifically asking about something coded in vb.net.

Comment: The page throws a 500 error. Start by removing the UpdatePanel and see what happens...

Comment: The problem is in the code-behind handling the form postback triggered by the DropDownList change event. You need to debug that code to find out what's going on. There is no way to answer this with the code shown.